# How to filter SQL rows, depending on a user's roles?

Tags: java, sql, rest, authorization

In my application each user can have multiple *authorization roles*. Depending on his roles the user should be allowed to see certain **excerpts of data**. I want to provide this data from my relational database via a REST-API.

For example:

```
table "Role"
UserName | Role
---------------------------
Anne     | ViewFreshFruits
Mike     | ViewFreshFruits
Mike     | ViewTinySoft

table "Company"
Name        | Address     | Role
--------------------------------------------
FreshFruits | 123 America | ViewFreshFruits 
TinySoft    | 543 Britain | ViewTinySoft

table "Contract"
ID  | CompanyName | Dollar
---------------------------
147 | FreshFruits | 15549
148 | FreshFruits | 16321
149 | TinySoft    | 2311
```

To implement the REST-Resource `http://api:8080/Application/Contracts/getAll` the data (without permission check) could simply be:

```
SELECT Contract.* FROM Contract
```

But Anne is only allowed to see 147 and 148. Mike can see 147, 148, 149. And Tomy must not get any results.

I started to implement the permission check like this:

```
SELECT Contract.* FROM Contract
INNER JOIN Company ON Contract.CompanyName = Company.Name
INNER JOIN Role ON Role.Role = Company.Role
WHERE User = @CurrentlyAuthenticatedUser
```

This kind of SQL gains complexity with the number of tables in my database. I'm looking for an easier approach: less complex and easier to maintain. Performance is not my primary concern.

**How can I filter certain rows of data, depending on the user, as simple as possible?**

I'm using a Microsoft SQL Server 2012, Java Tomcat 8 and Connection Pooling.

Answer (score 0):

How about stored procedures where you pass the role. Or to simplify you select use a view to hide some of the details.

**edit**

Create a view on company and authorisation tables (or a stored procedure or CTE)

`CREATE VIEW CompanySecurity AS   SELECT Company.*, role.username FROM Company INNER JOIN Role ON Role.Role = Company.Role`

If you want contract details join that view to CompanySecurity and filter on username

If you want to see Sales,  join sales to CompanySecurity and filter on username

Comment: If you need a simpler query, this is the best answer. But instead of a Stored Procedure, use a User Defined Function. It is limited to selects but it can be used as a table unlike Stored Procedures. Because the query is just a select, the best choice would be the UDF.

Comment: It seems like creating those stored procedures or functions would *move* the complexity into the database; but not *reduce* the complexity.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need some complexity of you want to add functionality!

Comment: You don't need to implement on every table. Is you need an extract of sales you would link via your view on companies which had security

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your last comment. What are "companies which had security"?

Comment: See Edit in my answer for example

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution. Until then I will stick to my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

That seems the easiest way to create and maintain.

If you want to have a faster SQL query, that doesn't need joins, you could create a materialized view based on that query, but without the `WHERE` clause and with the `User` on the column selection.

```
SELECT User, Contract.* FROM Contract
INNER JOIN Company ON Contract.CompanyName = Company.Name
INNER JOIN Role ON Role.Role = Company.Role
```

That way you would have a virtual table that keeps that query saved and up to date for fast authentication data retrieval. To `select` you would only need to:

```
SELECT * FROM MaterializedView
WHERE User = @CurrentlyAuthenticatedUser
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still not yet convinced, because the view definition is nearly as complex as my initial approach and I will end up with lots of database queries and depending on the number of users and contracts this might take lots of disk space.

Comment: Disk space won't be affected by sprocs or functions

Comment: As far as I know *materialized* views do cost disk space. Don't they?

Comment: @slartidan Yes, they do. That's why a query to it its faster, because they access the data on that materialized view and there is not need to compute the query. It's the old choice, between saving space (View) or processing (Materialized View).